# SP.Utilities.UrlBuilder.urlCombine Not working

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, csom, jsom

I am trying to concat two strings using urlCombine method like this:

```
SP.Utilities.UrlBuilder.urlCombine(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, AnotherUrl);
```

The AnotherUrl might contain a slash / and when it does, the result url will be like:

```
http://sitename/sites/myweb//anotherurl
```

So basically the urlCombine didn't work. Why is that? I still have duplicate urls.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'It didn't work'? It's doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Here is the function definition:

```
SP.Utilities.UrlBuilder.urlCombine = function SP_Utilities_UrlBuilder$urlCombine(path1, path2) {
    if (path1.endsWith('/')) {
        return path1 + path2;
    }
    else {
        return path1 + '/' + path2;
    }
};
```

As you can see, the function handles two cases.

1) The first path ends with '/'

- In this case all the function does is to concatenate both parts

2) The first path does not end with '/'

- In this case all the function does is to concatenate both parts with a '/' between them